# como deixar a div fixa em um local

Tags: css, html5

queria saber como faço para a div não quebrar o layout eu tenho o seguinte problema quando abro uma resposta de um comentário ele abre abaixo deste comentário, mas era pra ficar do lado ou algo do tipo olha [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no caso precisaria que independente do comentário ele fique no local certo segue código fonte:

Css

```
    /*Menu*/

.menu { width: 100%; height: 55px; position: relative; background: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid  #59ab66;}
.menu ul {margin-left: 3%; margin-top: 10px; position: relative;}
.menu ul li {display: block; text-align: center; float:left; margin-left: 1%; width: 8%;}
.menu ul li a { margin-top: -5px; }
.menu li a:hover { border-bottom: #64c3ea solid 2px; }
.menu li img   {border-bottom: none; float: none; margin: 4%;}

.menu li ul {display:none; }

.menu input {padding: 5px;}



.user ul li{width: 4%; float: left; position: relative;   }
.user ul li a,  .user ul li a:hover {background: none; border: none; float:none; }
.user .usuario {display: block; position: absolute; margin-left: 75%;}
.user .subuser{display: none; margin-top: 5px; height: 200px; width: 250% !important; padding: 5px; background-color: #64c3aa;}
.user .subuser li {background: #fff; width: 85%; }
.user .subuser li a:hover {color: #2B6FB6;}
.user ul li ul li {margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 10px; float: none;}
.user ul li ul a {background: none; text-align: left; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; }
.user ul li ul a:hover {background: none; color: #fff; }
.user img {width: 40px; height: 35px; border: 1px solid; border-radius: 100%;}
.img_user {width: 100px; border: none !important; border-radius: 0 !important;}
.noborder img {border: none !important; }

.user .acao {display: block; position: absolute; margin-left: 70%;}
.user .subacao{display: none; overflow: auto;  width: 700%;  height: 500px;   float:left; margin-left: -300%; background-color: #64c3ea;}


.user .subacao img{ border-radius: 0%;}
.user .subacao p{text-align: left;}
.sem {display: none; }


.points {margin-right: 32% !important; position: relative; float:right !important; }
.ocult {display: none;}

/*Relacionados*/

.relac {width: 150px; margin-right: 5%; height: 100px; background: #eee; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px; float:left;}
.relac p{text-align: center;}
.channels {width: 25%; margin-right: 5%; height: 100px; background: #eee; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 40px; float:left;}
.channels p{text-align: center;}
.about {width: 100%; float:left; margin-top: 20px;}
.img_about{width: 150px !important; height: 100px;}

/*Descrição*/

.exibir_desc {margin-left: 20%; width: 60%;  background: #eee; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 25px;   padding: 15px;}
.desc {margin-left: 20%; width: 60%;  background: #eee; margin-top: -25px;  margin-bottom: 40px; padding: 15px;}
.desc p{text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;}
div.hRule {height:0; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; border-top:5px dashed #ccc; margin-bottom: 5px;
}
div.hRule hr { display:none; }

/* Footer */

footer a {color:#59aed1;}
footer a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}


/* Paginação */

.pag a{color: #000}
.pag a:hover {color: #fff;}

/* Viwer */

.afastar {margin-left: 1%;}
.afastar_right {margin-right: 3%;}
.afastarcom {margin-left: 22% !important; height: 35px !important; background: #b26a6a ; color: #fff !important;}
.comentar {width: 100%;  margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 25px; }
.coment { width: 70%;  background: #eee; margin-left:15%; margin-bottom: 25px; float: left; min-height: 150px; position: relative;}
.coment p{margin-bottom: 5px;}
.coment img{width: 80px; margin-left: 2%; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 2%; height: 80px;}
.coment small{color: red;}
.localvideo{width: 100%;  margin-top: 25px;  background: #eee; float: left; min-height: 150px;}
.localvideo img{ margin-left: 1%; width: 80px; margin-top: 10px; float: left; margin-right: 2%; height: 80px;}
.descer {display: inline;}
textArea {width: 100% !important; background: #00D4FF; border: 2px solid #000; height: 250px;}
.viwer {width: 100% !important; height: 125px !important; background: #59aed1; border: 2px solid #000; }
.foto {width: 150px;    height: 125px; float:left}
.visualizaron {display: none; width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;  float: left; text-align: center;
                background: #eee; height: 40px; 
                height: 50px; padding: 5px; }
.visualizaroff { width: 100%; margin-top: 10px; padding: 10px; float: left; text-align: center;
                background: #eee; 
                height: 50px; padding: 15px;
}
.comentando { width: 60% !important; float: left;  }

.comentando {
    width: 60% !important;
    float: left;
}
.resposta {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 17%;
    width: 100%;
}
.resposta:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.resp {
    left: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.resp textArea {
    height: 50px !important;
    width: 80% !important;
}

/* Links */ 

a:visited {color:#000;}
a {color:#000;}

/* Espacamento */
.cimabaixo {margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;}

/* minimo heigth*/

.minimo {min-height: 900px;}

/* Notificações */

.notif {width: 100%;  height: 100px;  background: #eee; color: #000; margin-top: 20px;  float:left; white-space: pre-wrap; display: block;  }
.notif small{ width: 75%; float: left !important; text-align: left; margin-top: 15px; white-space: pre-wrap; }

.notif img{width: 15%; height: 80px; float:left !important; border: 3px solid #fff; }


/* Definições para todas as paginas */

.meio {width: 70%; margin: 0 15%; padding:40px 0;}
.user_menu {width: 10%; float: left; margin-top: 90px; padding:40px 0;}
.user_foto {width: 40%; height: 80px; margin-right: 10px; border: 2px solid #fff; border-radius: 10px;}

.definicao {width: 32%; height: 5px; float: left; text-align: center;}
.painel {width:90%; height: 225px; background: #fff; border: 2px solid #fff; border-radius: 10px; }

.notif a {background: none !important;}

/* Notificação */

.contador { width: 45%; position: relative; margin-top: -35px; font-weight: bold; color:#fff; background: #333; border: 1px solid #eee; border-radius: 100%;}
.img_notif {position: relative}
.acao_foto {width: 20% !important; height: 85px; float:left; margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;}
.notif_fundo {width:80%; background: #fff; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000 !important; padding: 10px; height: 60px; margin-left: 10%; }

/* Modal */

.window{
    display:none;
    width:50%;
    height:500px;

    position:absolute;
    left:25% !important;
    top:0;
    background:#eee;
    z-index:9000;
    padding:50px;

}



#mascara{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:9000;
    background-color:#000;
}

.fechar{display:block; text-align:right;}
.tit-modal{background: #00D4FF; text-align: center; border: 3px solid #000; padding: 10px; color: #FFF; font-size: 20px}
.input-modal {width: 100%; background: #00D4FF; border: 2px solid #000; color: #fff;}
.label-modal {text-align: center; padding: 5px; width: 100%;  color: #000; font-size: 15px !important;}
.btn-modal {margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 30%; width: 40%;}
.window .fechar{position:absolute; left:85%; top: 2%;  padding:5px 9px; background:#00D4FF;}
.window  .fechar{text-decoration:none; color:#fff; font-weight:200;}
.window  .fechar:hover{background:#09F; color:#fff;}
.window .text {height: 150px !important; color: #fff}

/* MYDIALOG */
.dialog{position:fixed; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); z-index:104; display: none; }
.dialog .loadsistem {padding: 30px; width: 20%; text-align: center; background: #fff; position: absolute; left:  50%; margin-left:  -160px; top: 50%; margin-top: -50px;}
.dialog .loadsistem {font-weight: bold; color: #069; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 14px;}
.dialog .loadsistem img {margin-bottom: 8px;}

.dialog .msg{background:#fff; position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; width:400px; height:160px; z-index:106; border:5px solid #CCC; display: none;}
.dialog .msg{padding:20px; margin-left:-220px; margin-top:-90px;}
.dialog .msg .tt{display:block; margin-bottom:10px; padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; font-size:40px; font-weight:600;}
.dialog .msg p{font-size:18px; font-weight:400; margin-top:10px;}

.dialog .msg .closedial{position:absolute; right:15px; top:15px; padding:5px 10px; background:#ccc;}
.dialog .msg .closedial{text-decoration:none; color:#fff; font-weight:200;}
.dialog .msg .closedial:hover{background:#09F; color:#fff;}

.dialog .accept{color:#0C0; }
.dialog .accept .tt{padding-left:45px; background:url(../../tpl/images/ms_icon_accept.png) center left no-repeat;}
.dialog .alert{color:#F90; }
.dialog .alert .tt{padding-left:45px; background:url(../../tpl/images/ms_icon_alert.png) center left no-repeat;}
.dialog .error{color:#900; }
.dialog .error .tt{padding-left:45px; background:url(../../tpl/images/ms_icon_error.png) center left no-repeat;}

.dialog .closemodal{position:absolute; left:50%; top:38%;  padding:5px 9px; background:#ccc;}
.dialog  .closemodal{text-decoration:none; color:#fff; font-weight:200;}
.dialog  .closemodal:hover{background:#09F; color:#fff;}



@media (max-width: 1438px){
    .viwer {width: 60%;}

}

@media (max-width: 1335px){
    .viwer {width: 60% !important;}
}

@media (max-width: 1390px){
    .min {width: 100% !important;}

    .user img {width: 40px !important;}
    .img_user {width:  100px !important;}
    .img_about{width: 200px !important; height: 100px;}
    .viwer {width: 60% !important;}

}

@media (max-width: 1348px){
    .min {width: 110% !important;}
    .user .subuser {width: 250% !important;}
    .user img {width: 40px;}
    .img_user {width:  100px;}
    .img_about{width: 200px !important; height: 100px;}

}

@media (max-width: 1225px){
    .min {width: 120% !important;}
    .user .subuser {width: 320% !important;}
    .user img {width: 40px;}
    .img_user {width:  100px;}
    .img_about{width: 200px !important; height: 100px;}


}

@media (max-width: 1125px){
    .min {width: 140% !important;}
    .user img {width: 40px;}
    .img_user {width:  100px;}
    .img_about{width: 200px !important; height: 100px;}

}

@media (max-width: 970px){
    .min {width: 160% !important;}
    .user img {width: 40px;}

    .img_user {width:  100px;}
    .img_about{width: 200px !important; height: 100px;}
    .user ul li {width: 40px;}



}

@media (max-width: 950px){
    .full h1{width: 100% !important; }
    .channels{width: 50% !important;}
    .viwer {width: 65% !important;}
    .ocult {width: 80% !important; display: block; }
    .min {display: none;}
    .user img {width: 40px;}
    .img_user {width:  100px;}
    .img_about{width: 200px !important; height: 100px;}
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
    .viwer {width: 70% !important; margin-left: 0%;}
    .foto {margin-left: -15%;}
}

@media (max-width: 725px) {
    .coment {width: 100%; margin-left: 0%;}
    .user .usuario {margin-left: 80%;}
    .ocult {width: 90% !important;  }
}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
    .viwer {width: 50% !important;}
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
    .viwer {width: 15% !important;}
    .user {margin-left: -40%;}
    .user .subuser {margin-left: -80%;}
    .user .subuser li {font-size: 14px;}
    .img_about {width: 200px !important;}
    .relac {width: 100px; font-size: 10px; }
    .relac p {margin-top: 8px;}
    .afastar {margin-left: 8%;}
    .full {white-space: nowrap; }
    .channels {width: 40% !important; font-size: 10px;}
    .channels p{margin-top: 8px;}
}
```

html

```
 <div class="comentando">
                   <p><?=nl2br($comentario)?></p></div>
                   <div class='fl-right resposta'>Responder<input type='hidden' value='<?=$big[id] ?>' name='idcoment'>
                   </div>
                   <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
                       <form method='post'><textarea></textarea>  

                           <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
                       </form>
                   </div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Tu quer que a div para responder fique fixa no lado direito do comentário é isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apliquei seu estilo, e funcionou aqui.
Verifiquei que a div esta fechada com um  a mais

```css
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #59ab66;
}

.menu ul {
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 8%;
}

.menu ul li a {
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  border-bottom: #64c3ea solid 2px;
}

.menu li img {
  border-bottom: none;
  float: none;
  margin: 4%;
}

.menu li ul {
  display: none;
}

.menu input {
  padding: 5px;
}

.user ul li {
  width: 4%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.user ul li a,
.user ul li a:hover {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  float: none;
}

.user .usuario {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 75%;
}

.user .subuser {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250% !important;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #64c3aa;
}

.user .subuser li {
  background: #fff;
  width: 85%;
}

.user .subuser li a:hover {
  color: #2B6FB6;
}

.user ul li ul li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: none;
}

.user ul li ul a {
  background: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.user ul li ul a:hover {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.user img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.img_user {
  width: 100px;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.noborder img {
  border: none !important;
}

.user .acao {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 70%;
}

.user .subacao {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 700%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -300%;
  background-color: #64c3ea;
}

.user .subacao img {
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.user .subacao p {
  text-align: left;
}

.sem {
  display: none;
}

.points {
  margin-right: 32% !important;
  position: relative;
  float: right !important;
}

.ocult {
  display: none;
}


/*Relacionados*/

.relac {
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.relac p {
  text-align: center;
}

.channels {
  width: 25%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  float: left;
}

.channels p {
  text-align: center;
}

.about {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.img_about {
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 100px;
}


/*Descrição*/

.exibir_desc {
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.desc {
  margin-left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  background: #eee;
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.desc p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

div.hRule {
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 5px dashed #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

div.hRule hr {
  display: none;
}


/* Footer */

footer a {
  color: #59aed1;
}

footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/* Paginação */

.pag a {
  color: #000
}

.pag a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Viwer */

.afastar {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.afastar_right {
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.afastarcom {
  margin-left: 22% !important;
  height: 35px !important;
  background: #b26a6a;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.comentar {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.coment {
  width: 70%;
  background: #eee;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.coment p {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.coment img {
  width: 80px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: 80px;
}

.coment small {
  color: red;
}

.localvideo {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background: #eee;
  float: left;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.localvideo img {
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 80px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: 80px;
}

.descer {
  display: inline;
}

textArea {
  width: 100% !important;
  background: #00D4FF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 250px;
}

.viwer {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 125px !important;
  background: #59aed1;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.foto {
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  float: left
}

.visualizaron {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  height: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.visualizaroff {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.comentando {
  width: 60% !important;
  float: left;
}

.comentando {
  width: 60% !important;
  float: left;
}

.resposta {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 17%;
  width: 100%;
}

.resposta:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.resp {
  left: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.resp textArea {
  height: 50px !important;
  width: 80% !important;
}


/* Links */

a:visited {
  color: #000;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}


/* Espacamento */

.cimabaixo {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* minimo heigth*/

.minimo {
  min-height: 900px;
}


/* Notificações */

.notif {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  display: block;
}

.notif small {
  width: 75%;
  float: left !important;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.notif img {
  width: 15%;
  height: 80px;
  float: left !important;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
}


/* Definições para todas as paginas */

.meio {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 15%;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.user_menu {
  width: 10%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 90px;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.user_foto {
  width: 40%;
  height: 80px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.definicao {
  width: 32%;
  height: 5px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.painel {
  width: 90%;
  height: 225px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.notif a {
  background: none !important;
}


/* Notificação */

.contador {
  width: 45%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.img_notif {
  position: relative
}

.acao_foto {
  width: 20% !important;
  height: 85px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.notif_fundo {
  width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000 !important;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}


/* Modal */

.window {
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25% !important;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
  z-index: 9000;
  padding: 50px;
}

#mascara {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: #000;
}

.fechar {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}

.tit-modal {
  background: #00D4FF;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 20px
}

.input-modal {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00D4FF;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.label-modal {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.btn-modal {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30%;
  width: 40%;
}

.window .fechar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 85%;
  top: 2%;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  background: #00D4FF;
}

.window .fechar {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.window .fechar:hover {
  background: #09F;
  color: #fff;
}

.window .text {
  height: 150px !important;
  color: #fff
}


/* MYDIALOG */

.dialog {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 104;
  display: none;
}

.dialog .loadsistem {
  padding: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -160px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.dialog .loadsistem {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #069;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.dialog .loadsistem img {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.dialog .msg {
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 160px;
  z-index: 106;
  border: 5px solid #CCC;
  display: none;
}

.dialog .msg {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: -220px;
  margin-top: -90px;
}

.dialog .msg .tt {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.dialog .msg p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dialog .msg .closedial {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.dialog .msg .closedial {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.dialog .msg .closedial:hover {
  background: #09F;
  color: #fff;
}

.dialog .accept {
  color: #0C0;
}

.dialog .accept .tt {
  padding-left: 45px;
  background: url(../../tpl/images/ms_icon_accept.png) center left no-repeat;
}

.dialog .alert {
  color: #F90;
}

.dialog .alert .tt {
  padding-left: 45px;
  background: url(../../tpl/images/ms_icon_alert.png) center left no-repeat;
}

.dialog .error {
  color: #900;
}

.dialog .error .tt {
  padding-left: 45px;
  background: url(../../tpl/images/ms_icon_error.png) center left no-repeat;
}

.dialog .closemodal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 38%;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.dialog .closemodal {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.dialog .closemodal:hover {
  background: #09F;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width: 1438px) {
  .viwer {
width: 60%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1335px) {
  .viwer {
width: 60% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1390px) {
  .min {
width: 100% !important;
  }
  .user img {
width: 40px !important;
  }
  .img_user {
width: 100px !important;
  }
  .img_about {
width: 200px !important;
height: 100px;
  }
  .viwer {
width: 60% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1348px) {
  .min {
width: 110% !important;
  }
  .user .subuser {
width: 250% !important;
  }
  .user img {
width: 40px;
  }
  .img_user {
width: 100px;
  }
  .img_about {
width: 200px !important;
height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1225px) {
  .min {
width: 120% !important;
  }
  .user .subuser {
width: 320% !important;
  }
  .user img {
width: 40px;
  }
  .img_user {
width: 100px;
  }
  .img_about {
width: 200px !important;
height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1125px) {
  .min {
width: 140% !important;
  }
  .user img {
width: 40px;
  }
  .img_user {
width: 100px;
  }
  .img_about {
width: 200px !important;
height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 970px) {
  .min {
width: 160% !important;
  }
  .user img {
width: 40px;
  }
  .img_user {
width: 100px;
  }
  .img_about {
width: 200px !important;
height: 100px;
  }
  .user ul li {
width: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 950px) {
  .full h1 {
width: 100% !important;
  }
  .channels {
width: 50% !important;
  }
  .viwer {
width: 65% !important;
  }
  .ocult {
width: 80% !important;
display: block;
  }
  .min {
display: none;
  }
  .user img {
width: 40px;
  }
  .img_user {
width: 100px;
  }
  .img_about {
width: 200px !important;
height: 100px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
  .viwer {
width: 70% !important;
margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .foto {
margin-left: -15%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 725px) {
  .coment {
width: 100%;
margin-left: 0%;
  }
  .user .usuario {
margin-left: 80%;
  }
  .ocult {
width: 90% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .viwer {
width: 50% !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 570px) {
  .viwer {
width: 15% !important;
  }
  .user {
margin-left: -40%;
  }
  .user .subuser {
margin-left: -80%;
  }
  .user .subuser li {
font-size: 14px;
  }
  .img_about {
width: 200px !important;
  }
  .relac {
width: 100px;
font-size: 10px;
  }
  .relac p {
margin-top: 8px;
  }
  .afastar {
margin-left: 8%;
  }
  .full {
white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .channels {
width: 40% !important;
font-size: 10px;
  }
  .channels p {
margin-top: 8px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="comentando">
  <p>comentario 1</p>
</div>

<div class="comentando">
  <p>comentario 2</p>
</div>

<div class="comentando">
  <p>comentario 3</p>
</div>


<div class=' resp' style=''>
  
  <form method='post'>
<textarea>Minha resposta</textarea>
<input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: aconteceu a mesma coisa

Comment: Então acredito que seja outra coisa que esta quebrando seu código, pois se executar o código que enviei, veja que tem três linhas (que seria os comentários) um textarea(onde colocaria o que quer comentar) e o botão da forma que você precisa.
Coloque o código css e hml que esta criando esse formulário para facilitar na ajuda.

Comment: coloquei o código completo do css para facilitar

Comment: Fiz uma edição no código acima (Apenas html) e ao executar veja que se mantém na lateral

Comment: fiz umas alterações aqui acho que agora deu certo obrigado pela atenção